# change image source with javascript function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display completely static images from satellite map.

For example,I need to display 5  static images where only latitude and longitude is defined.

I did it like this [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6um90vvm/#&togetherjs=1aA8vbp7Mr)

I did it using static map API.

```
Example:
<img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=20.1,20.1,NY&zoom=18&size=200x200&maptype=satellite"/>
```

But I need to change it because those images should appear in a dynamically way.
For some reasons the javascript function is not executed. Help me!

```
function addImageSource(number,lat, lon) {
 var imageSource = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + lat + "," + lon + ",NY&zoom=18&size=200x200&maptype=satellite";
$("#item" + number).attr("src", imageSource);
}

addImageSource(1,20.123456, 21.123456);
addImageSource(2,21.123456, 21.123456);
addImageSource(3,22.123456, 21.123456);
addImageSource(4,23.123456, 21.123456);
addImageSource(5,24.123456, 21.123456);
addImageSource(6,25.123456, 21.123456);
```

The html code:

```
<div id='item1'> <img/> </div>
<div id='item2'> <img/> </div>
<div id='item3'> <img/> </div>
<div id='item4'> <img/> </div>
<div id='item5'> <img/> </div>
<div id='item6'> <img/> </div>
```

Can somebody help me please, how can I  achieve this in the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the image source to `div` instead of `img`. Also fixed some syntax error.

1. `var imageSource` is a string and should end with `"`. Hence updated `=satellite` to `=satellite";`.
2. There was a comma missing before `NY&zoom`. So updated `NY&zoom` to `,NY&zoom`.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/6um90vvm/1/).

```js
function addImageSource(number, lat, lon) {
  var imageSource = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + lat + "," + lon + ",NY&zoom=18&size=200x200&maptype=satellite";
  $("#item" + number + " img").attr("src", imageSource);
}

addImageSource(1, 20.123456, 21.123456);
addImageSource(2, 21.123456, 21.123456);
addImageSource(3, 22.123456, 21.123456);
addImageSource(4, 23.123456, 21.123456);
addImageSource(5, 24.123456, 21.123456);
addImageSource(6, 25.123456, 21.123456);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='item1'> <img/> </div>
<div id='item2'> <img/> </div>
<div id='item3'> <img/> </div>
<div id='item4'> <img/> </div>
<div id='item5'> <img/> </div>
<div id='item6'> <img/> </div>

<br/>
Example:
<br>
<img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=20.123456.1,21.123456,NY&zoom=18&size=200x200&maptype=satellite" />
```